# How to raise/move/adjust this service wire for a pavilion roof build?

Tags: electrical, deck

I am planning on building a fixed roof up from this pergola. However, a complication first: the power utility's service wire is too close. The service wire is currently around 18 inches above the pergola. The fixed roof will increase the height of the pergola probably 12-18 inches, as it will be a gabled roof up. The roof will then be too close to the service wire (and possibly touching it, depending on the roofing approach).

[image]

It seems like my options are:

1. to slide the power wire to be closer to the property line, but I don't think this will give me enough clearance.
2. to raise the service conduit run up 2 feet.
3. to remove all the joists and cut the posts down, then rebuild the joists back up

My questions are:

- Are these my options, or are there other, simpler options to consider?
- Who does this? Does this require my power company (ComEd in Chicago) to do this work, or can it be done by an electrician? And is permitting typically involved?

Thank you for your input!

EDIT: I won't be touching any of the lines myself, I'll be relying on professionals for that work!

Comment: A photo from the other direction would help.  You're talking about changing a conduit that isn't even pictured here.

Comment: @robertchapin it is not conduit, it is overhead wiresà.

Comment: Side note: Do make sure your existing structure can support the added weight of a roof, any snow load your locale may get and the weight of several humans walking around on top (during construction, at least).

Answer (score 1):

You missed an option:

4. Contact the power company and have them move the wires up the pole so they hang higher to clear the new construction.

Seriously, don't mess with your power feed. 120v is enough to shock and kill you, the 240v coming in on those lines is *more* than enough to do the job. Even if the shock itself doesn't kill you, falling off the ladder/roof while you're messing with them will likely finish the job.

Sure the PoCo may charge you to move the lines, but it'll be less than funeral costs if you die and *much* less than hospitalization costs if you live.

Comment: Oh, moving the lines myself was never one of the options!
I've already contacted the power company. Awaiting to hear what they say.

Comment: Whew! Obviously, that wasn't clear to me from your question... I would go over your plans with them and have them tell you how high it needs to be moved. You _might_ need to raise the weatherhead on your house (where the lines enter the house) to get the height you need. An added expense, to be sure, but still the only reasonable way to go unless you "shorten the structure".

Answer (score 0):

You could move the service attachment point to the corner of the building nearest the pole, somewhere in this area:

[image]

then run through conduit to wherever it needs to be.  If you do it on the lower end of the area I marked, maybe you could run the conduit through your new roof so it won't be visible.

This will be more expensive than just raising the wire.

Comment: POCO alert: they might have rules about how short the run has to be before the meter... Obviously, there are ways to work with that, but be prepared.

Comment: I don't own the building next door, and I believe (but don't know for sure) that there is code preventing power lines from spanning into other properties.

Comment: Ah! I thought that was your building.  It looks like your new structure is butt up against that wall, and you are obstructing those two lowest windows.  That's why I thought it was yours.  Ok.